# Haskell library import syntax

Tags: haskell

Sorry for the very basic question: In GHCi, is there a difference between `import Library.Name` and `:m +Library.Name`? They seem equivalent, but I assume there's a reason for the alternative syntax.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would include `import` in the source code, which is more general, whereas `:m` is a ghci - specific command (for convenience).

You can use `ghci> :m + Module1 ... ModuleN` to load multiple modules. Use `-` instead of `+` to unload the module. Because `ghci` is interactive, I'd stick to `:m`, unless your workflow is rather: edit your `.hs` file, save it, and reload it. Then the `import` would be more suitable (and has more features e.g. [qualified imports](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Import)).

The `import` directive would also work if you later decide to compile the program using for example `ghc`. You can selectively import only specific functions: `import Data.List (sort)` would import only sort, so is pollutes the namespace less.

Comment: So is :m simply for concision?

Comment: It occurs to me that :m also permits the *removal* of libraries once they've been imported.

Answer (score 10):

You're right that `import Module` and `:module + Module` are identical, but there are a few reasons for the `:module` (henceforth abbreviated `:m`) syntax.

1. It's older.  GHCi really used to just be the inside of an `IO` `do` block; now it supports every part of the language, so we can do `import`s.  (It looks like [GHCi 6.6.x didn't support `import`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.6-latest/html/users_guide/ch03s04.html#ghci-scope), but [GHCi 6.8.1 did](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.8.1/html/users_guide/interactive-evaluation.html#ghci-scope); we didn't get full support for top-level declarations until [GHCi 7.4.1](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.4.1/html/users_guide/interactive-evaluation.html#ghci-decls).)
2. It lets you import multiple modules at once.  `:m + M1 M2 M3` is the same as writing `import M1`, `import M2`, and `import M3` each on a new line.
3. It lets you un-import modules: `:m - M` will remove `M`'s contents from what's currently in scope at the prompt.
4. It lets you import an interpreted module so that you can see the *whole* scope.  This is what happens when you `:load File.hs`; you find that you're in the module `*File`, and can *e.g.* see everything that `File` imports and even everything that it doesn't export.  If you have an interpreted module `MI` loaded, then you can use `:m + M1 *MI M3` to bring `M1` and `M2` into scope the ordinary way, and `MI` into scope the special way.

For completeness, though, `import` syntax does offer us three things that `:m` doesn't:

1. Qualified imports.  It's much nicer to be able to do `import qualified Data.Map as M` and use `M.lookup` than to have to do `Data.Map.lookup` or suffer ambiguity errors.  (Note that every package that's installed is available fully qualified in GHCi, so `import qualified Module` alone buys you nothing.)
2. Import lists.  Even if I have the functions from `Data.Map` qualified with `M`, I can still do `import Data.Map (Map)` to just bring the type into scope unqualified.
3. Import `hiding`.  The reverse of the above; maybe I'm writing my own sorting routine, so I can do `import Data.List hiding (sort)`.

You can also check out [§2.4.5, "What's really in scope at the prompt?", in the GHC (7.6) user's guide](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6-latest/html/users_guide/interactive-evaluation.html#ghci-scope).

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer; if I hadn't already marked the thread "solved," I would have picked it.